# Help, my sceen is black due to orca! (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

So, I was using linux one day and I decided to fiddle with the settings, I peeked in the universal access settings in order to look at some settings, I diddled with the contrast in there and now my entire screen is black with only my cursor remaining, I can tell that everything is still there, I just can't see it, ive tried using my custom terminal command to enter `killall orca` and Alt + Super + S, that didn't work, please I need help.

P.S. If your wondering how I wrote this without my computer, I used another device.

Comment: The only setting in there I can see that might impact on contrast is `High Contrast` which you might have set to `On` with the slider. First item under `Seeing`

Comment: @24601 Well you see the problem with that solution is that I cant see the gui because of that setting.

Comment: Try to ssh into the black screen machine.  If you can't ssh, then mount the disk on another computer and modify the files (after backing up personal files).

Comment: @PierreALBARÈDE Ok, I will try this SSH thing to get into the my machine, if that doesnt work there are only 2 options, either someone finds a series of default short-cut combos to get to the setting I changed and disable it, or do the disk mounting thing.